# wp.svgPainter cannot init error, causing issues with admin panel

Tags: wp-admin

I've recently discovered that my add media buttons were not working properly and it looks like an error with the javascript being loaded. The error is exactly as described in this link:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cannot-read-property-init-of-undefined/

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    // detection for browser SVG capability
    if ( document.implementation.hasFeature('http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Image', '1.1' ) ) {
        $( document.body ).removeClass( 'no-svg' ).addClass( 'svg' );
        wp.svgPainter.init(); <--- error here
    }
});
```

The jist of it is `wp-admin/load-scripts.php` is not loading the `wp-admin/js/svg-painter.js` for whatever reason, I've attempted to disable all plugins with no success. I've also checked my functions.php for anything dealing with the admin js and no luck. I'm not sure what is the best approach to resolve this issue, any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this as I never have

Comment: @JessMcKenzie yes I have a cacher plugin on nginx called google pagespeed that modified the javascript - I disabled it

Answer (score 0):

The issue was found under the Google Pagespeed settings, specifically:

`pagespeed EnableFilters defer_javascript;`